# IF/COUNT/FIND formula help required

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bit of a dilemma with the `IF COUNT FIND` functions in Excel. I am currently researching goal times in soccer matches and have various games with goal times shown as follows (as an example);

`23;56;85` (this would be in cell `C2` for purpose of this question) The semi colons cannot be changed, this is how they are shown in the data I have, over 50,000 rows of data.

If I apply the formula below into a cell it will give the value "1" as it recognises the number 56.

```
=IF(COUNT(FIND({56},C2))>0, 1, 0)
```

However the formula does not work when I ask it to search for any single digit number from 1 to 9, for example the formula below would return the value "1" also because it is picking up the number 5 from the times of 56 and 85.

```
=IF(COUNT(FIND({5},C2))>0, 1, 0)
```

How can I adjust to formula so it picks up single digit goal times only? Any helps appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to match the surrounding semi-columns in the process:

```
=IF(COUNT(FIND({";56;"},";"&C2&";"))>0, 1, 0)
```

Notice that (in both formulas) we match something surrounded by `;`, but we also surrounded the searched string with `;` at each side to handle the edges positions.

Your formula can be simplified further:

```
=--ISNUMBER(FIND(";56;",";"&C2&";"))
```

But your initial formula is good if you want later to match *one of many* values, which you can put in the array.